# Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer on Separate Projects in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm currently developing a web application using ASP.Net MVC 3.

I have this structure in my Solution:

- WebApp Project (Models, Views, Controllers)
- Service Layer (Interfaces, Business Logics)
- Domain Project (Repositories, Interfaces, EF)
- EF4POCO Project (POCO)

Just wanna know if it's the correct way, I have my DATA ACCESS LAYER and BUSINESS LOGIC LAYER on separate projects.

Comment: This has *definitely* been asked before. Please try the search function (both here on StackOverflow and e.g. Google...) before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your application layers are loosely coupled (e.g. by using interfaces/dependency injection/etc), they could be in the same project.

But yes, splitting them in separate projects is common practice and is likely to be more maintainable and scalable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, with this structure I'm having problem with JOIN query results from EF. Do you have any idea on how to pass JOIN query results to Controller from Repository -> Service Layer? 'Coz what I normally do is I use the POCO classes to pass query result to Controller, which is normally from a single table.

Comment: Add new POCOs for holding the join results. These POCOs are not managed by the DbContext, but are only for containing and transferring data.

Comment: Is it okay to add new POCO class manually under EF4POCO Project? These classes were created using POCO Entity Generator.

Comment: So, what will happen is, POCOs will also serve as ViewModels, right?

Comment: Maybe rename the EF4POCO project to 'Entity' or 'Model' (or something) and in that project have separate namespaces for EF generated POCOs and DTOs? Then you can keep all model related stuff in 1 project. And yes, these DTOs can also serve as view models.